# Debugging PHP memory leak. Tracking the reference count?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, reference-counting

I have a rather large PHP script that is leaking memory. I have been able to figure out what object is leaking, but I have not been able to find out where in the script it is leaking. Some part of my script is keeping a reference to the leaking object.

Is there some way that I can track (and preferably backtrace) where/when a PHP object has it's reference count increased or decreased?

Answer (score 2):

You can use profiling tools to find out what is leaking your memory i prefer http://xdebug.org/ and http://code.google.com/p/webgrind

http://derickrethans.nl/xdebug-and-tracing-memory-usage.html

Comment: Thanks. I am familliar with XDebug and function tracing. But do you know how I can use it to track where my leaking object is referenced from in my code?

Comment: you can try to track with webgrind it will show you all your invoked functions-methods, it wont show memory usage, but i think you may track them by time spent-usage

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

- http://www.php-debug.com
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php
- http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

Also, I suggest to write the code in a easy-to-debug manner and separate the debugging procedures from the code.

Comment: I have already used XDdebug to find out what object is leaking. What I want to know now is where it is leaking? I.e. where in my code are references to that object kept? Can XDebug be used for that?

Comment: How do you used the breakpoints to locate where the object is leaking? Hard to come with a "general" solution.

Comment: Hence my question. I had hoped there was some kind of way to track or trigger when the Zend Engine increments or decrements an object's internal reference count.